# Why does this query not give me the most recently-inserted rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code working 100%, but it doesn't show the latest details required from the MySQL database.

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM wdclients ORDER BY 'id' DESC LIMIT 6";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $latest1;
    print $db_field['clientid'];
    echo $latest2;
    print $db_field['cname'];
    echo $latest3;
    print $db_field['cname'];
    echo $latest4;
}
```

The problem now is that I require the code to show only the 6 latest entries in the database. I have over 500 clients in the database but it only shows the first 6 and never update.

The "ID" field in database has set the auto-increment value.

Comment: how do you define latest ? based on id ?

Comment: Remove the quotes around `id` column.

Comment: your forgetting the start offset eg: `SELECT * FROM wdclients ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,6`

Comment: Please format your posts in future.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: That is not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @BN said, remove quote around `id`. Make your query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wdclients ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

or, if you insist, change it into something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wdclients ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0,6
```

notice the difference between ( **'** ) and ( **`** )

Comment: I don't see any difference between your reply here and the query on your question.

Comment: Working Code: `SELECT * FROM wdclients ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,6`

Comment: You don't know that the newest rows have the highest ID.

Answer (score 1):

Although it usually does the trick, sorting by id is no guarantee to get the latest data entered. You'd better add a `DATETIME` field like date_created or date_updated that contains a timestamp when the record was either inserted or last updated, depending on your wishes. That way you'll be sure to get the data in proper chronological order.

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you used single quotes instead of backticks to delimit that field name.

```
SELECT * FROM wdclients ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 6
```

Ordering by a string literal (`'id'`) doesn't really do anything, so you ended up with the "natural" ordering.

That is, the physical ordering in storage, since MySQL tables have no inherent ordering. And, even though you set `AUTO_INCREMENT` on that ID field, it is not *guaranteed* to yield sequential values forever (e.g. IDs from old, deleted rows could be used).

You should set the ID yourself with a known unique, sequential value if you want to define an actual ordering by insert time.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have put id in regular single quotes. You have to use backquotes in order for MySQL to parse it into a value:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM wdclients ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 6";
```

Comment: "Have this code, working 100%, but it doesn't show the latest details required"